# Why is my php files not responding to the css file linked to it?

Tags: php, css, forms

I'm trying to change to color of the error alerts on this php file. By my css files doesn't seems to respond. Can you help me figure out the reason? I'd like to make my alerts blue and bigger.

Here's the form :

```
<div id="dv_global_form"> 
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p class="required">Required fields *</p>
        Name:<input type="text" name="name" <?php echo"value='$nameValue'"?>>     <span class="required"> *</span><?php echo"<span class='required'>     $nameErr</span>" ;?></span><br>
        Surname:<input type="text" name="surname"<?php echo"value=$surnameValue"?>><span class="required"> *</span><?php echo"<span class='required'> $surnameErr</span>" ;?></span><br>
        Date of Birth:<select name="dob">
        <?php dob()?>
        </select><span class="required"> *</span><?php echo"<span class='required'> $dobErr</span>" ;?><br>
        Email:<input type="email" name="email" <?php echo"value=$emailValue"?>><span class="required"> *</span><?php echo"<span class='required'> $emailErr</span>" ;?>
        <h3>Gender<span class="required"> * </span></h3>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
    <?php echo"<p class='required' > $genderErr</p>" ;?>
</div>
```

Here's the php file containing the functions:

```
 function dob(){
 echo "<option></option>";

for($i=1989;$i<2001;$i++){
    if($i==$_POST['dob']){
        echo "<option selected='selected'>$_POST[dob]</option>";
    }else{
        echo "<option>$i</option>";
    }
}
}

 // Validate fields
 $nameErr= $surnamErr=$emailErr= $dobErr=$sexErr=$genderErr="";
 $nameValue=$surnameValue=$dobValue=$emailValue="";

  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==POST){

if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    $nameErr="Name is required field";
}else{
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/",$_POST['name'])){
            $nameErr="Only letters and white space allowed";
        }else{
            $nameValue=$_POST['name'];
        }
}

if(empty($_POST['surname'])){
    $surnameErr="Surname is required field";
}else{
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zAZ]*$/",$_POST['surname'])){
            $surnameErr="Only letters and white space allowed";
        }else{
            $surnameValue=$_POST['surname'];
        }
     }
if(empty($_POST['dob'])){
    $dobErr="Date of birth is required field";
}

if(empty($_POST['email'])){
    $emailErr="Email is a required filed";
}else{
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
           $emailErr="This email format is not valid";
        }
        $emailValue=$_POST['email'];
}

if(empty($_POST['gender'])){
 $genderErr="Gender is a required field";
}else{

      }





 }
```

And here's the css :

```
       .required{
        color:blue;
        }

        #gender{

        color:blue;
       }
```

Comment: both .required and #gender are not working or only #gender is not working ?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with your question. What's the HTML that's rendered to the browser?

Comment: Both, but my alerts are red for some reason.

Comment: Where did you put your css? Did you put <style> tag? Can you show the complete construct please (as one block of code)?

Comment: Have you tried `color: blue !important;`? It's hard to tell since there is no reference to what could possibly be making something red.